# How Clear is this Interview Question?

Tags: java

We are interviewing for a Senior Java Development Role and all three people that we have asked to complete this question gave us the same incorrect answer. The question was done before the interview so they had a lot of time. Their solutions seemed to sort the input by parentId and then childId instead of creating a tree and from the input and then traversing the tree to find the correct order. Is the question not clear enough?

**Question:**

The following is a simple skills and presentation test for the Java Developer role which must be completed before the telephone interview.

REQUIRED:

1. JUnit Test
2. Implementation of NodeSorter interface

QUESTION:

We have a Java object that looks something like this:

```
public class Node {

    public int id;
    public Integer parentId;

    public Node(int id, Integer parentId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }
}
```

For example the following list of Node(s) might be displayed graphically as:

Node (id: 1, parentId: null), Node (id: 2, parentId: 1), Node(id: 3, parentId: 1), Node(id: 4, parentId: 2), Node(id: 5, parentId: 3)

```
              Node (id: 1)
             /            \
            /              \
           /                \
          /                  \
      Node (id: 2)         Node (id : 3)
         /                    \
        /                      \
       /                        \
      /                          \
  Node (id: 4)                 Node (id : 5)
```

Assumptions:

1. There will be always at least one Node
2. There will be one and only one Node with a null parentId
3. Every Node will have a valid parentId except for the Node which has a null parentId

Requirements:

1. Write a class that implements the following interface that will receive a List of Node(s) and order them from top to bottom (Nodes that are higher in the tree must be before the nodes lower in the tree. Eg. Node 1 on the top of the tree must be before node 4 which is on the bottom of the tree). Nodes on the same level will be in order of their id so the Node with id=2 will appear before the node with id=3 in the diagram above.

Interface:

```
    public interface NodeSorter {
        public List<Node> sort(List<Node> unSortedNodes);
    }
```

Test Data:

Test Case 1:

---

Diagram of Input:

```
              Node (id: 1)
             /            \
            /              \
           /                \
          /                  \
      Node (id: 2)   Node (id : 3)
         /                    \
        /                      \
       /                        \
      /                          \
  Node (id: 4)           Node (id : 5)
```

Input: Node (id: 2, parentId: 1), Node(id: 4, parentId: 2), Node (id: 1, parentId: null), Node(id: 3, parentId: 1), Node(id: 5, parentId: 3)

Output: Node (id: 1, parentId: null), Node (id: 2, parentId: 1), Node(id: 3, parentId: 1), Node(id: 4, parentId: 2), Node(id: 5, parentId: 3)

Test Case 2:

---

Diagram of Input:

```
              Node (id: 1)    
             /            \
            /              \
           /                \
          /                  \
      Node (id: 5)   Node (id : 2)
         /                    \
        /                      \
       /                        \    
      /                          \
  Node (id: 4)           Node (id : 3)
```

Input: Node (id: 5, parentId: 1), Node(id: 4, parentId: 5), Node (id: 1, parentId: null), Node(id: 3, parentId: 2), Node(id: 2, parentId: 1)

Output: Node (id: 1, parentId: null), Node (id: 2, parentId: 1), Node(id: 5, parentId: 1), Node(id: 3, parentId: 2), Node(id: 4, parentId: 5)

Comment: how often do you solve this problem in the job that you are interviewing for?

Comment: we do actually build up trees from id/parentId data in our application. but i mostly chose this question because i thought it would be at an appropriate level since i was asked a similar question an interview i had.

Comment: ohh revenge question uh?

Comment: i didn't have a problem with the question. i just like stealing from others.

Comment: @drscroogemcduck: I find it seriously confusing to see a constructor taking both an int and an Integer. There's a reason to have wrapper classes around primitives, but your example is definitely not one of them. You're completely subverting the type system using a Java idiosynchrasy that has no reason to be (the only explanation I see is that you're doing it as to not 'mistake' the int for an Integer and vice-versa but this is broken on so many counts that I don't know where to start).

Comment: I dont like that you gave the correct answer in the first paragraph - it predisposed me to come up with that answer, and not the answer i would have come up with had i not known the correct answer.

Comment: @drscroogemcduck: In addition to that, it is mindboggling to see a Node class using int arithmetic to point to other nodes instead of using a Node reference, like it is done in every single OO implementation of trees and Nodes. Your Node class is really amazingly weird. I've rarely see so many confusing things in only 6 lines of Java code.

Comment: @Lowlevel: we are using Integer because we are using a null parentId to represent not having a parent. we are using parentId/id and not references because that's part of the question.

Comment: @LowLevel: Maybe Node is a bad name for the class. NodeRecord might be better. It's not meant to be a proper OO Node but rather like a node record you might get from a database.

Comment: What do I do if the input Node graph has cycles? Nothing in the assumptions guarantees these can't occur.

Answer (score 14):

I would say that this is pretty darn unclear.  You want an unsorted list for input, and a sorted list as output.

Each item in the output list is a tree-node, but there is no balance enforced on the tree.  Couldn't the user just read in the values for all the nodes, sort them, and then loop over the sorted values creating new nodes, each of which point at the previous node, and essentially be done...they've created a grossly unbalanced tree (no branches), but who cares?

That seems correct to me, but if I was interviewing I would not be very happy with this answer, because I would be wondering why the tree was there at all.

Nothing in this question indicates to me that I should do anything like what you're suggesting: "creating a tree and from the input and then traversing the tree to find the correct order."

Comment: you are correct that you don't need to create a tree to get the correct answer. one of our internal solutions sorted them by child id, then iterated over the tree (without creating one) using the breadth-first search algorithm.

Comment: The question is kind of ambiguous to me since it seems you are looking for a specific answer when there is more than one way to solve the problem. I can think of one way to solve it using a tree and one way to solve it and create the tree after ordering the nodes.

Comment: As stated now, it is *not* ambiguous.

Comment: @drscroogemcduck: How do you do those things if you can't go from a parent to its children? You'll first need to make a mapping from parents to children, which I would call a tree.

Comment: It is a simple assignment.  The assumptions, input, and desired output are clearly stated.  Just because you add more assumptions and then question the input format doesn't make the question less clear.

Comment: @reineierpost: you can go from the parent to children by either looping through all the Nodes and looking for nodes whose parentId == id of the current parent or more efficiently setting up a hashmap/treemap. in the case of a treemap the structure is very similar to building a tree anyway...

Answer (score 11):

Honestly, the question seems pretty clear to me.

Have you tried asking them **why** they chose to sort by list ID and then node ID? Did they think that solved the problem? If so, what is their reaction when confronted with input for which it doesn't work?

Even if they didn't answer the question correctly, by asking them these questions you can both learn more about them and understand what in your question isn't clear enough.

Comment: +1 Exactly.  Just because they got a question wrong doesn't mean they don't know what's going on.  Discussing their solution will tell you more about the interviewee than just marking "got it wrong" on your problem.

Answer (score 9):

How about updating the test cases to add tests that would fail given the incorrect solutions that are being provided?

It seems like that would be an obvious way to make the question a bit clearer. And then if they still don't understand the question or find it unclear given the question/test cases provided they can request additional information before completing their solution.

Answer (score 4):

It appears to me that you're basically asking them to sort a list based on two factors - the parent ID and then the list ID.  If that's the case, you could just simplify the question and not worry about the whole "tree structure" idea and just ask them to write a sort for a list based on two factors.

Comment: Sorting by parent ID and then list ID doesn't work, if the nodes aren't numbered based on their placement in a tree (i.e. parent is ID 10, children are smaller IDs).

Comment: this is why i'm concerned the question wasn't clear enough because this wasn't what we wanted them to do. you can have a low parentId and be lower in the tree than another node that has a high parentId. it just so happens all the test cases worked if you sorted by parentId :(

Comment: I initially missed the "on the same level" qualification in the requirement statement.  That would explain the wrong answers.

Answer (score 4):

The question is clear in the input/output.

What data structure or algorithm should be used in the implementation is not specified hence, any can be used ( which is good ).

If the resulting code gives the expected output then, it is correct, even if they don't use a Tree ( because it was not in the specification )  if the output is wrong, the solution is wrong, even if they use a Tree.

Answer (score 4):

I think the question itself is quite clear, but the choice of data in your test cases is leading people to attempt an incorrect solution (sorting by parentid). Perhaps this was deliberate?

If you want to make it more likely that respondents will get the correct answer, then you could include a test case that demonstrates that parent ids can be larger than child ids.

I'm not sure that would improve this as an interview question, however: it seems the question as written has the benefit of testing someone's ability to come up with a solution that's correct for all cases, not just for the samples they are provided.

Answer (score 3):

You can ask them to output the nodes in <strike>pre-order</strike> level-order, that ways the question would be crystal clear.

Comment: the order is level-order (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal). maybe more evidence that the question isn't clear :(

Comment: i think pre-order for first example would be: 1 2 4 3 5 as opposed to: 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: thanks . for the correction . it is level-order only .edited . dont know how to strike out

Comment: maybe *add* level-order, rather than replacing anything?  That way, if the candidate happens to remember it, it helps them (and tells you something potentially interesting), but you're not testing memory of specific technical terms.

Comment: I thought to add "level order" also.  I deal with graphs and trees all the time and I had to do a few mental gymnastics to understand this question.  If anywhere it had mentioned the words tree and/or "level order traversal", I would have skipped to the end and started coding an answer.  Maybe you are trying not to mention graphs, trees, breadth first traversal, etc. in order to avoid forcing a solution.  But I think this only makes it harder for everyone.  Those who understand the concepts will know there are multiple ways to solve this... those who don't won't be helped by the vagueness.

Answer (score 0):

Did you give examples of input and output to the interviewees like you did in the posting here? If you just give the rules without an example, I think someone could be forgiven for misunderstanding.

Personally, I think it's a good question. It's simple enough that you're not asking the applicant to spend days working on it, it has a clear, well-defined correct output, and a correct solution demonstrates a knowledge of how to manipulate data structures, which is pretty basic for a good developer. And I see you said that you asked applicants to do it before the phone interview, which I take it means do it at home, so they're not sitting in a room with an interview staring at them while they struggle and thus under artificial pressure.

The only real flaw I see is that it is not clear to me what the input is. You say the input is a list of nodes, apparently Node objects, but how does the programmer have any assurance that this list of nodes actually forms a tree? Is he supposed to simply assume that it is all valid input? Or is he supposed to validate it? I think you would be better to say that the function must accept the root node of a tree and then discover what nodes exist by traversal, rather than making the double problem of supplying the list and forcing the programmer to make sense of it.

It's a whole lot better than most of the interview questions I've gotten in my life, which tend to be questions like "How many years experience do you have with ...", "What is your greatest fault as an employee?", and "Do you have experience with Foobar version 3.9.7.6? Oh, you've only used version 3.9.7.5, sorry, we use 3.9.7.6 here."

My only quibble is, What does this question have to do with JUnit testing? You start out saying it's about JUnit testing but I don't see how it relates to that at all.

Answer (score 0):

The question is **CLEAR**. You are asking for then BFS of the tree.

It's an interesting question for reviewing 1) abstraction capabilities; 2) order and style in programming 3) care for algorithm order (the big-O).

My answer for all that "how many times do you do that in your job" comments is:

- this question intends to evaluate:

  - the capacity of abstraction
  - the theory background
  - use of data structures and algorithms

If you can do that, then you are not a simple *database-systems-oriented-basic-programmer*.